# Re-docking/pining panel in layout window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, layouts, qgis-print-layouts

Using QGIS v3.4.4 and accidentally closed the `"Item Properties"` and `"Items"` panels in the layout window.

Cannot now get them to re-dock/pin back into place. They will only float. Have googled everywhere and tried every suggestion I would find but nothing works.

Comment: Right click on an empty spot in the Print Composer and select `"Item Properties Panel"` and `"Items Panel"`. And then stack them manually with the mouse to the desired place.

Comment: I have tried this, turning the panels on is no issue. The "stacking them" is the issue. I assume it is supposed to be as simple as grab the floating window and hold it to the side or top to get a stacking option however no stacking option is available.

Comment: Can you please show that unavailability?

Comment: I'm not sure how i would show that? When I turn on the "Items Panel" for instance it comes up as a floating window. I can click on it and drag it around to position anywhere on my screen i would like, however no matter where I drag it to or hover it over there are no options for it to dock anywhere within the window.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and neither of the proposed solutions is working for me in 3.4.4. 1. Double-clicking the title bar of the Item Properties panel does nothing once it's undocked, unlike the other Panels. 2. I tried Liam's fix and restarted QGIS. I was able to re-dock the Item Properties panel, but only as part of the main toolbar across the entire top of the GUI. Other panels un-dock and re-dock normally on the right side panel bar. Very strange. [![Weird top-docking of Item Properties panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBSHj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBSHj.png) It appears that th

Answer (score 2):

Double click on the title bar of the floating toolbar and it will dock itself again

Answer (score 2):

Workaround in the QGIS console (will force-dock all panels):

```py
for w in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):
    w.setFloating(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Close all panels, save your project, close and reopen.  Turn on layers panel and identify results panel, highlight one layer, identify a feature.  The identify panel should give you a result. Now double click on the title bar.  It should dock immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue also using 3.18.  While in the Print Composer, click on View --> Toggle Full Screen (check it) then select the panel you want to doc and pull it to the right until it docs.  You can then add any additional panels to the first one by dragging it into the same area.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, the docking is a bit tricky.

I had to turn all the panels and toolbars off, turn on the Item Properties panel I had un-docked, then move it to the side of the screen where it then docked, and turn on all of the other panels. This re-set it.